# Spring Cache Abstraction & custom converter

Tags: spring, caching, converters, abstraction

I an trying to use an "own made" object as part of the key in a @Cacheable annotation:

```
@Cacheable(value = "tecdocData", key = "'TCDD:stos::'.concat(#stos)")
List<TecDocData> getTecDocData(Collection<SimpleTecDocObject> stos);
```

This leads to an error with following stacktrace (a relevant part):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Problem invoking method: public java.lang.String java.lang.String.concat(java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:73)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:97)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E:(pos 0): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from java.util.HashSet<?> to java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectionHelper.convertArguments(ReflectionHelper.java:281)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:61)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.util.HashSet<?> to type java.lang.String for value '[SimpleTecDocObject [guid=GUID-C2DBD976-79F0-42FB-94CE-9352DE43A184, locale=de, version=1]]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type com.sxp.setix.api.SimpleTecDocObject to type java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:169)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:66)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type com.sxp.setix.api.SimpleTecDocObject to type java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:276)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToStringConverter.convert(CollectionToStringConverter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:35)
    ... 105 more
```

As far as I can see, spring do make an attempt to convert a HashSet but fails to convert the contained "SimpleTecDocObject" values.

In order to solve this issue I defined a converter and registered it in my Spring configuration. This was done quite straight ahead as documented in "7.5 Spring 3 Type Conversion" [7. Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Converter class:

```
public class SimpleTecdocObjectConverter implements Converter<SimpleTecDocObject, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(final SimpleTecDocObject source) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        result.append(source.getGuid()).append(source.getLocale()).append(source.getVersion());

        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean id="tdConverter" class="com.kion.lsg.service.tecdoc.converter.SimpleTecdocObjectConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Unfortunately this seems not to work. I get exactly the same exceptions as above. Spring abstraction seems to ignore the conversionService defined above and take some default one.

***Solution:***
Lotsa thanks to Akshay Singhal

Instead of using a converter one can use a static key generator inside of the SpEL expression:

```
@Cacheable(value = "tecdocData", key = "T(com.kion.lsg.service.tecdoc.converter.SimpleTecDocObjectCollectionKeyGenerator).generateKey(#stos)")
List<TecDocData> getTecDocData(Collection<SimpleTecDocObject> stos);
```

For example with a KeyGenerator defined as following:

```
public class SimpleTecDocObjectCollectionKeyGenerator {
    public static String generateKey(final Collection<SimpleTecDocObject> stos){
        List<String> tecdocIdsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SimpleTecDocObject sto : stos){
            tecdocIdsList.add(sto.toString());
        }

        Collections.sort(tecdocIdsList);

        return tecdocIdsList.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the converter is being ignored because you have multiple contexts being loaded, like a ROOT context loaded by a ContextLoaderListener and a web application context loaded for a servlet. And your configuration is being overwritten by the context loaded later.

However that is just a guess, and admittedly not a very informed one, because I don't really know how your application is bootstrapped.

Regardless, looking at your problem, a custom converter might not be the simplest solution. Te whole point of a cache `Key` is to create a unique identifier out of the arguments, so that subsequent request with the same arguments can be served from the cache.

Because you have `"'TCDD:stos::'.concat(#stos)"` as your `key` expression, Spring is forced to use a converter to compute the string value of `#stos`. A much simpler solution would be to simply change your expression to `"'TCDD:stos::'.concat(#stos.toString())"`, and rely on the `Collections` `toString()` method to delegate to your class's `toString()` method. - Thus creating a string out of the argument, which will be unique for each set of argument.

If you don't want to implement `toString()`, another option would be to create a Class whose sole responsibility is to convert `Collection<SimpleTecDocObject> stos` into a String. Create a static method in this utility class, use whatever key creating logic you want in this method, and call it from the `spel` expression. Something like `T(SimpleTecDocObjectCollectionKeyGenerator).generateKey(stos)`. With this method you can even abstract away `TCDD:stos::` to inside the key generator utility class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the "#stos.toString()" worked fine. Unfortunately I wasn't able to do it with the KeyGenerator alternative.

This one doesn't work :

```
"@Cacheable(value = "tecdocData", key =  T(SimpleTecDocObjectCollectionKeyGenerator).generateKey(stos)")"
```

This is how the generator looks like:

```
public class SimpleTecDocObjectCollectionKeyGenerator {
public static String generateKey(final Collection<SimpleTecDocObject> stos){
    List<String> tecdocIdsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (SimpleTecDocObject sto : stos){
        tecdocIdsList.add(sto.toString());
    }

    Collections.sort(tecdocIdsList);

    return tecdocIdsList.toString();
}
```

}

Seems like it is never get called.

Comment: This is strange.. the T() syntax is standard SpEL.. do you see any errors at all? or is the method just not cached?

Comment: The method is not cached. I will raise the log level of net.sf.ehcache and org.springframework.cache and see if some debug output is usefull for locating the problem.

Comment: Now I found where the error was.
First of all one has to use the full qualified class name. And than I've forgot the "#". See below the right declaration:
@Cacheable(value = "tecdocData", key = "T(com.kion.lsg.service.tecdoc.converter.SimpleTecDocObjectCollectionKeyGenerator).generateKey(#stos)")

Comment: Great. I'm a little surprised you didn't accept the answer I gave.. but anyways, I'm glad it worked out for you.